# i want to compare this three terms in C ++ code

Tags: c++, operators

If there is such a code in C++.

```
j = 5;
k[i] = j * ((k[i] > 0));
```

Then, if `k [i]` is `1`, so `(k [i]> 0)` becomes `1`.

So the last `k [i]` is `5`.

If `k [i]` is `-1`, so `(k [i]> 0)` becomes `0`.

So the last `k [i]` is zero.

Then I wonder

```
j = 5;
k[i] = j * ((10 > k[i] > 0));
```

here

If `k[i] = 5`, `k[i]` is greater than `0` and less than `10`.

so `(10> k [i]> 0) = 1` and `j * 1 = 5`?

Can I use three comparison operators at the same time?

Thanks you.

Comment: Yes you can. `(10 > k[i] > 0)` is valid code, but don't work as intended. But using `k[i]= (10 > k[i] && k[i] > 0) ? 0 : j` instead would be more better for future understanding and correct (See https://www.cprogramming.com/reference/operators/ternary-operator.html).

Comment: if `k[i]` is negative this'll return true when it shouldn't.

Comment: why `k[i]` has to be an element of an array? Your example would be much easier to graps if you had just `int i,j,k;` (and if you include the declarations)

Answer (score 1):

It will compile, but it won't work. You need to write `(10 > k[i] && k[i] > 0)`

Answer (score 1):

No c++ doesn't support comparing a variable to multiple values at the same time.
Confusingly your comparison may even compile but it won't do what you think it does. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int b = 21;
    if ( 5 < b < 20 )
    {
        std::cout << "OK";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Fail";
    }
}
```

will compile (with a warning) but will print `OK` not `Fail`. What is happening is that you actually have:

```
if ( (5 < b) < 20 )
```

Which evaluates to:

```
if ( true < 20 )
```

`true` is less than 20 so the comparison returns true. You need to fully state the comparison you want to execute:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int b = 21;
    if ( (5 < b) && (b < 20) )
    {
        std::cout << "OK";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Fail";
    }
}
```